# Laravel Eloquent fetch nested compact json data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two different `Models`

`App\Models\Team;`

and

`App\Models\Member;`

Where my `Team` Model has this function

```
public function memberList()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Member');
}
```

---

and I'm using this code to show it on my blade

```
 $team = Team::with('memberList')->get();
 return view('front.pages.custom-pages-index', compact('team'));
```

here's my columns for the tables

**MemberTable**

[image]

**Team Table**

[image]

Now I'm trying to access the compact data using this foreach

```
@if(count($team))
     @foreach($team as $field)
         //Name of Team
         <h1>{{$field->name}}</h1>
         //Member
          ....
     @endforeach
@endif
```

This is the sample content of compact data when I tried to access the `{{ $team }}` on blade file

```
 [{
"id":1,
"name":"Executive Team",
"created_at":"2020-05-26 04:38:27",
"updated_at":"2020-05-26 04:38:27",
"member_list":[{
    "id":1,
    "team_id":1,
    "position":1,
    "name":"Chris White, PH.D",
     "member_position":"President, Founder and CEO",
  ...And other member per specific team
```

The problem is I want to fetch on blade the members per specific teams

**UPDATE**

When I tried at least to access the `name` inside of the `member_list` using foreach

`$field->member_list->name`

I'm getting an error like this

`Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

[image]

Tried to `var_dump($field->member_list)`

[image]

Tried this `@php dd($field->member_list); @endphp`

[image]

Comment: can you comment your foreach loop and dump your field_member variable inside of if statement before comment?

Comment: @umuttaymaz shows null but when I tried to `{{$team}}` member_list is not null

Comment: actually it shouldn't be written as NULL. you can add $field->member_list != NULL too inside of your if statement. !empty($field->member_list) OR !is_null($field->memberlist) OR $field->member_list != NULL

Comment: Hmm tried your suggestion, the problem is getting the same error.

Comment: Delete all of conditions and just give a condition. count($field->member_list) > 0

Comment: Got this error.. count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable hmm

Comment: can you dump with @dump blade directive. it would be better. member_list is coming from relationship it should be an array

Comment: I updated my post, hmm did I do it correctly? Is it necessary it to have something like this `@if( $team as $key >= $value )`

Comment: We wrote !is_null(memberlist) it should be member_list by the way. It can cause this error

Comment: you cannot supply $field->member_list to foreach, all the data have been pulled you only need to iterate over the $team, please show the original loop that gave you the error

Comment: Can you try to use `$field->memberList` instead?
PHP is case sensitivity.

Comment: one more thing, did you install MDBootstrap using npm?

Answer (score 1):

Because member_list item of variable field is an array and "name" isn't a key of this array. You should use another loop for your member list inside of your main loop.

```
@if(count($team))
 @foreach($team as $field)
     //Name of Team
     <h1>{{$field->name}}</h1>

     //Member
     @if(!empty($field->member_list) OR !is_null($field->memberlist))
        @foreach($field->member_list as $member)
        <h2>{{$member->name}}</h2>
       @endforeach
     @endif
 @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Followed your answer but got this error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Do you have any team which is not have any member?

Comment: You should check for $field->member_list is not empty or not null before foreach. Teams without any member cause this error

Comment: Tried something like this `@if(!empty($field->member_list) || $field->member_list != NULL) @foreach($field->member_list as $member) ...` the team name shows but the member of some team are not showing. Also either I use `!empty` or `!= NULL` the members not showing but team name shows.

Comment: change $field->member_list != NULL to !is_null($field->member_list) and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In my Member.php (Model)

Added this

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team', 'id', 'team_id');
}
```

In my Team.php (Model)

```
public function memberList()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Member', 'team_id', 'id');
}
```

Controller

```
  $team = Team::with('memberList')->get();
  return view('front.pages.custom-pages-index', compact('team'));
```

Blade

```
  @if(count($team) > 0)
        @foreach($team as $field)
                {{$field->name}}
               @foreach($field->memberList as $member)
                  {{$member->image}}
               @endforeach
        @endforeach
 @endif
```

Need to map first the Team and Member models using its Primary key and Foreign Keys

And call the json column `memberList`